# Django how to get all the column names from the given sql table (model.py)

Tags: python, sql, django, database

I am trying to fetch all the columns from the given SQL table in Django (model.py). I found most of the tutorials discussing getting a specific column using its column name. In my case, I can expect unknown columns in the future and I want to see them in the Django dashboard. Is there any possible way to get all the column names from the given table without giving any column names inside the model.py (Django)?

Comment: if you given SQL table is a string.maybe the only way do this is use `from django.db import connection` to perform a sql query `cursor.execute()`

Answer (score 0):

You can try below

```
from .model import MyModel

all_fields = MyModel._meta.fields
#or
all_fields = MyModel._meta.get_fields
```

docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/meta/

Comment: The above lines in view.py actually will return the column names that we have already initialized inside the manage.py. I would like to know whether we can get the entire columns/table without initializing any columns inside model.py. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Retrieving all field instances of a model**

```
MyModel.get_fields(include_parents=True, include_hidden=False)
```

Returns a tuple of fields associated with a model. get_fields() accepts two parameters that can be used to control which fields are returned:

**include_parents**

- True by default.
- Recursively includes fields defined on parent classes.
- If set to False, get_fields() will only search for fields declared directly on the current model.
- Fields from models that directly inherit from abstract models or proxy classes are considered to be local, not on the parent.

**include_hidden**

- False by default.
- If set to True, get_fields() will include fields that are used to back other field’s functionality.
- This will also include any fields that have a related_name (such as ManyToManyField, or ForeignKey) that start with a “+”.

get_fields() returns a tuple and each element is a Model field type, which can't be used directly as a string. So, `field.name` will return the field name

```
my_model_fields = [field.name for field in MyModel._meta.get_fields()]
```

The above code will return a list containing all fields name